# iOS app - push notification alert when entity date property reaches deadline

Tags: ios, nsdate, push-notification, uialertview, uievent

I'm trying to make an app that warns me when a current event is going to end. I have an entity (the event), with a date attribute - which is the end date for the event. How can I set a notification alert to pop up for like two days before the event ends? Any links to other tutorials or any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using UILocalNotification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Local Notifications for this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194